# Polymer! Call a function in Ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, callback, polymer

i just dont know how to call a another polymer function in a ajax success.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        // these variables are shared by all instances of app-globals
        var firstName = "John";

        function setData(data) {
            firstName = data;
            console.log("Data gesetzt:" + firstName);
        }

        Polymer({
            ready: function () {
                this.setTest("Example"); //Works
                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://www.jsv-lippstadt.de/?json=get_category_posts&slug=" + this.from,
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        this.setTest(); //Doesnt work
                    }
                });

            },
            setTest: function () {
                console.log("hi");   
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Thats the console log from the success function: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

So how can i call the setTest: function(){} in my callback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the context option for the jQuery ajax call so that `this` in the success handler has the right value (it will normally point to the jqXHR object):

```
    Polymer({
        ready: function () {
            this.setTest("Example"); //Works
            $.ajax({
                // set the context option so this will have the desired value
                // in the success handler
                context: this,
                async: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.jsv-lippstadt.de/?json=get_category_posts&slug=" + this.from,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                error: function () {
                    alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    this.setTest(); // should work now
                }
            });

        },
        setTest: function () {
            console.log("hi");   
        }
```

---

Or alternately, you could save the `this` value like this into another variable that can then be used from the callbacks:

```
    Polymer({
        ready: function () {
            // save this value into another variable so it can be used in callbacks
            var self = this;
            this.setTest("Example"); //Works
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://www.jsv-lippstadt.de/?json=get_category_posts&slug=" + this.from,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                error: function () {
                    alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    self.setTest();    // should work now
                }
            });

        },
        setTest: function () {
            console.log("hi");   
        }
```